# How to include query string in url and staying on the same page?

Tags: php

I generated a tabs of months with anchor tag and href is equal to query string of ?m=1&y=2014. The year part will be incremented accordingly with next and previous button. By the way this is in a wordpress environment.

--Code--
Next and previous button for year.

```
<div class="table-header">
            <div class="table-header-wrapper">
                <div class="prev"></div>
                <div class="year"><?php echo $current_year; ?></div>
                <div class="next"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

--Code--
Tab months

```
<?php
                    for ( $monthNum = 1; $monthNum <= 12; $monthNum++ ) :
                        $month = date( 'M', mktime( 0,0,0, $monthNum, 1, $current_year ) ); // month in 3 letter format e.g. Jan
                        $current_monthNum = date( 'n' ); // current month in number
                ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo strtolower( $month ); ?> month" data-month="<?php echo $monthNum; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url( 'admin-events-list' ).'/?'.addQuery( array( 'm' => $monthNum, 'y' => $current_year )); ?>" class="<?php echo ( $current_monthNum == $monthNum ? 'current' : '' ); ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></a>
                    </div>
                <?php
                    endfor;
                ?>
```

Comment: You should use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @ROX, thats what I think too but is it still doable even the page loads data when clicking on the month tabs? I will be loading in data for current month selected.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP its not possible as PHP is a server side scripting language.

You can achieve it with jQuery.

[Hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin serves your need.

Here, you can change hash of url on some event.

And fire some event on `haschange`.

You can change your hashes on `Previous` and `Next` buttons.

Comment: This still doesn't work as it is for hash only not for query string like http://domainname.com/?m=11&y=2014. It suppose to append those query string when clicking one of the tab months.